# C++ Thread-safe Queue Implementation input and return types

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue

I found the below code from this post: [Why is std::queue not thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762248/why-is-stdqueue-not-thread-safe)

```
#pragma once

#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

    template <typename T>
    class SharedQueue
    {
    public:
        SharedQueue();
        ~SharedQueue();

        T& front();
        void pop_front();

        void push_back(const T& item);
        void push_back(T&& item);

        int size();
        bool empty();

    private:
        std::deque<T> queue_;
        std::mutex mutex_;
        std::condition_variable cond_;
    }; 

    template <typename T>
    SharedQueue<T>::SharedQueue(){}

    template <typename T>
    SharedQueue<T>::~SharedQueue(){}

    template <typename T>
    T& SharedQueue<T>::front()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
        while (queue_.empty())
        {
            cond_.wait(mlock);
        }
        return queue_.front();
    }

    template <typename T>
    void SharedQueue<T>::pop_front()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
        while (queue_.empty())
        {
            cond_.wait(mlock);
        }
        queue_.pop_front();
    }     

    template <typename T>
    void SharedQueue<T>::push_back(const T& item)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
        queue_.push_back(item);
        mlock.unlock();     // unlock before notificiation to minimize mutex con
        cond_.notify_one(); // notify one waiting thread

    }

    template <typename T>
    void SharedQueue<T>::push_back(T&& item)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
        queue_.push_back(std::move(item));
        mlock.unlock();     // unlock before notificiation to minimize mutex con
        cond_.notify_one(); // notify one waiting thread

    }

    template <typename T>
    int SharedQueue<T>::size()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
        int size = queue_.size();
        mlock.unlock();
        return size;
    }
```

I'm pretty confused on a few parts:

1. Why is the front() function returning T& (a reference to some type T)?
2. Why is push_back taking in const T& and T&& in as types?

Are they necessary here?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

```
template <typename T>
T SharedQueue<T>::pop_front()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
    while (queue_.empty())
    {
        cond_.wait(mlock);
    }
    T retFront = queue_.front();
    queue_.pop_front();
    return retFront;
}
```

Comment: I guess I'm just trying to understand why they're there. For instance, the front() function returns a reference to T. Doesn't that mean it can be used as an lvalue? So, the front() function is essentially setting the first value of the queue?

Comment: Oh I understand front() now. Thank you. I was mistaken about what it meant. For the first push_back() though, why does it have to take in const T& as an input? Couldn't const T work just as well? Why does it need the reference to the input?

Comment: @cmed123 Because that would make another copy of the object to construct the function parameter. You don't want to make a copy though, you only want to pass on the object to the actual `queue_`'s `push_back`. If you'd add your questions from the comments to the question post, I think it would be much more focused and clearer to answer.

Comment: @walnut There is no additional template argument in `push_back` and `T&&` is not a forwarding reference at all. I misread the code, sorry.

Comment: @walnut Thanks! I see. In my case, I do actually want to make a copy of an object though. I don't want the reference since I will keep updating the object I'm pushing in. So I'm guessing I should just change it to const T instead?

Comment: @cmed123 It is not about the reference being saved in the queue. The queue always saves a copy. But if you pass by-value into `push_back`, then there will be *another* copy operation for `push_back`'s parameter before the queue element is copy/move-constructed from the parameter. This copy would always be pointless waste of resources.

Comment: @walnut Ah I see, so passing in by reference is due to speed. It's faster to do it that way. Thanks so much. Sorry one more question, the parameter to the second push_back is a universal reference/forward reference right?

Comment: @cmed123 No, it is just a rvalue reference. It is not a forwarding reference because `T` is not a template parameter of the function (it is a template parameter of the class). (This was also the misunderstanding Evg and I had above.)

Comment: @walnut Got it. Thank you so much for your help! Appreciate it!

Comment: If moving is always cheap, just one `push_back(T)` would suffice. But we cannot assume that property for an arbitrary type `T`. This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035417/is-the-pass-by-value-and-then-move-construct-a-bad-idiom).

Comment: @deleted comment: Yes, `front` is not safe when another thread may be calling `pop_front` at the same time. The interface in the code replicates that of `std::deque`, which may indeed be problematic in multithreaded code. @cmed123: If you want to be able to use `front` safely while another thread may be calling `pop_front`, then you need to have it return by-value, not reference. That limits its usability, but makes it safe for that situation.

Comment: @walnut Thank you for the clarification. I actually have been testing it and am getting errors with multithreaded code. One thread is doing push_back() and with the other thread, I've tried front(), pop_front(), and push_back() and I'm getting a mutex lock error. Is there anything you notice in the implementation that I don't see? The locking seems right to me.

Comment: @walnut Hm interesting, yeah I thought it seemed a bit awkward. I updated my post with a modified version of that (and combined both front() and pop_front()). It seems a bit messy since I have to add the extra lines though

Comment: @cmed123 Your new version is not safe if `T`'s copy constructor can throw exceptions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035691/why-doesnt-stdqueuepop-return-value and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417822/thread-safe-queue-with-front-pop.

Comment: Edited comment: Honestly, now that I had a better look at it thanks to that deleted comment by @IInspectable, I don't see how that queue implementation can work at all under multithreading. front and pop_front need to be combined into one operation, otherwise a thread cannot access and pop the front element without another thread potentially intervening between the locks.

Comment: @walnut I see, thanks for those links! Appreciate it! It makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Using of void push_back(T&& item) can significantly reduce CPU/memory usage (If your argument is available for "move"). "Can" doesn't mean "will".

Why two forms of push_back are supported? imho, "by design" (it's developer design). In some cases your can use single form with forward.